# ElasticSearch : Aggregations on one field not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I have few documents in one index in elastic search. When I aggregate by one of its fields, I do not get any results. The field's mapping is

```
{
    "type": "string",
    "index": "not_analyzed"
}
```

I have another field that is indexed in the same manner but I am able to do aggregations on that. What possible causes can be there for this? How do I narrow down the issue?

Edit : The Elastic Search version is 1.6.0 and I am running the following query for aggregation:

```
{
   "aggregations": {
     "aggr_name": {
       "terms": {
         "field": "storeId",
         "size": 100
       }
     }
   }
}
```

where "storeId" is the field I am aggregating on. The same aggregation works on another field with the same mapping.

Comment: Please provide ES version, mapping, query example and response. String data type is not supported for a long time https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/string.html

Comment: @Ivan : Added the details. My elastic search version is not current.